# Scala Spark group as per value change

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have following dataset :-

```
ID    Sensor    State    DateTime
1      S1         0      2018-09-10 10:10:05
1      S1         0      2018-09-10 10:10:10
1      S1         0      2018-09-10 10:10:20
1      S1         1      2018-09-10 10:10:30
1      S1         1      2018-09-10 10:10:40
1      S1         1      2018-09-10 10:10:50
1      S1         1      2018-09-10 10:10:60
1      S2         0      2018-09-10 10:10:10
1      S2         0      2018-09-10 10:10:20
1      S2         0      2018-09-10 10:10:30
1      S2         1      2018-09-10 10:10:40
1      S2         1      2018-09-10 10:10:50
2      S1         0      2018-09-10 10:10:30
2      S1         1      2018-09-10 10:10:40
2      S1         1      2018-09-10 10:10:50
```

Required Output

```
ID  Sensor  State   MinDT                  MaxDT
1   S1       0     2018-09-10 10:10:05    2018-09-10 10:10:20
1   S1       1     2018-09-10 10:10:30    2018-09-10 10:10:60
1   S2       0     2018-09-10 10:10:10    2018-09-10 10:10:30
1   S2       1     2018-09-10 10:10:40    2018-09-10 10:10:50
2   S1       0     2018-09-10 10:10:30    2018-09-10 10:10:30
2   S1       1     2018-09-10 10:10:40    2018-09-10 10:10:50
```

I want to make a group on the basis of sensor change values and I'll be needing the range when the value is changed. Any help please. I tried a simple approach by initialling the value in variables then iterating over each row to check change in value and storing the ResultSet in an array but this approach is not distributed on cluster. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just group in this way and achieve the results as you desired.

```
df.groupBy("ID", "Sensor", "State")
            .agg(
                date_format(max(to_timestamp($"DateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").alias("MaxDT"),
                date_format(min(to_timestamp($"DateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").alias("MinDT"))
            .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| ID|Sensor|State|              MaxDT|              MinDT|
+---+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  2|    S1|    0|2018-09-10 10:10:30|2018-09-10 10:10:30|
|  1|    S2|    1|2018-09-10 10:10:50|2018-09-10 10:10:40|
|  2|    S1|    1|2018-09-10 10:10:50|2018-09-10 10:10:40|
|  1|    S1|    0|2018-09-10 10:10:20|2018-09-10 10:10:05|
|  1|    S2|    0|2018-09-10 10:10:30|2018-09-10 10:10:10|
|  1|    S1|    1|2018-09-10 10:10:50|2018-09-10 10:10:30|
+---+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```